# "The media query -ms-viewport has been deprecated." What should I use instead?

Tags: html, css

In my CSS I have an -ms-viewport media query, but in the browser (edge) it says that the media query is deprecated and that there is no result. What should I replace it with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@viewport` without the vendor prefix `-ms-`, this will work on (most) browsers. 
On Edge this feature was "momentarily" disabled a few years ago. See the following: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7970618/

Comment: that link is dead now, 404